# How to attach files to a Powershell function and send it through MS Outlook?

Tags: email, powershell, outlook, send

I've got this code:

```
Function Mailer ($MSubject, $MBody, $File){
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)
$Mail.To = "abc@contoso.com"
$Mail.Subject = $MSubject
$Mail.Body = $MBody
$Mail.Attachments.Add($File)
$Mail.Send()
}
```

I will work if I provide the exact path in the function by assigning it to the $File variable. However, I wish to make this universal for different subjects, bodies and paths. Shall I set the file path as global? What are your thoughts?

Thanks in advance :)
Piotr

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I use to send emails out,

```
$from="ServerAdmin@Contoso.com"
$to="worker@contoso.com"
$cc=@("John.Doe@Contoso.com", "Jane.Doe@Contoso.com")
$subject="Weekly reports"
$attach="c:\SchTsk\Reports\Server_Inventory_$((Get-Date).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy')).csv","C:\SchTsk\Reports\VMPlatform_$((Get-Date).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy')).csv"
$body="This email contains weekly reports ran on the domain.<br>In an effort to reduce inbox spam, reports that generate separate files are now being attached to one weekly email."
Send-MailMessage -from $from -To $to -cc $cc -subject $subject -SmtpServer snmp.relay.contoso.com -Body $body -BodyAsHtml -Attachments $attach
```

Comment: Yeah, I know this. But I want to have this in a function.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the function works fine. The problem was with the variable for the file path I was calling to.